# What causes a Server to read the last message of a Client over and over again?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, server, posix

Given that code for a server, a really unexplainable bug appears in the job_read function.

If this server is connecting with clients, everything seems to work fine - although there might be a handful of other bugs. If a client connects, a new thread will be started, which then reads the input of the client. If the client sends a message this message will be spread to all other clients. The client is run through the terminal. If you stop the client with STRG + C everything will work just fine, but not if you crash it when you exit the terminal.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUFLEN 255
#define MAX_CONNECTIONS 128
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 30

struct JOB_INFO {
    int socket_ids[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
    bool end_of_program;
    int open_cnncts;
    pthread_mutex_t socketids_changingMutex;
};

struct SERVER_INFO {
    struct sockaddr_in serv_add;
    struct sockaddr_in cli_adr;
    socklen_t cli_len;
    pthread_t write_thread;
};
//Global Variables
FILE* plog_file;

void delete_socket(int socketid, struct JOB_INFO* pjob_data);
void* job_read(void*);
void* job_write(void*);
void error(const char* msg);
void setUpFileStream(int argc, char* argv[]);
int setUpConnections(struct SERVER_INFO* pserver_data, char* port_numc);
void enterConnectingLoop(struct SERVER_INFO* pserver_data, struct JOB_INFO* pjob_data, int sockfd);

void error(const char* msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    setUpFileStream(argc, argv);

    int sock_fd;
    struct JOB_INFO job_data;
    job_data.end_of_program = false;
    job_data.open_cnncts = 0;

    struct SERVER_INFO server_data;
    //Create mutex
    if(pthread_mutex_init(&(job_data.socketids_changingMutex), NULL) < 0){
        error("Could not initialize Mutex");
    }
    //Initialzing threads and create write_thread
    pthread_create(&server_data.write_thread, NULL, job_write, (void*)&job_data);

    //Setup for connections
    sock_fd = setUpConnections(&server_data, argv[1]);
    fprintf(plog_file,"Listening...");
    fflush(stdout); //For unknown reason this is needed.
    enterConnectingLoop(&server_data, &job_data, sock_fd);

    job_data.end_of_program = true;
    close(sock_fd);

    pthread_join(server_data.write_thread, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&job_data.socketids_changingMutex);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void* job_read(void * p){

    char** pc = (char**)p; //allow pointer arithmetic
    int new_sock_fd = *((int*) (pc[1]));  //Casting
    struct JOB_INFO* pjob_data = ((struct JOB_INFO*) (pc[0])); //Casting

    ssize_t n; //Error catching variable
    ssize_t m; //Error catching variable
    char buffer[BUFLEN];
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    sprintf(name, "Client %d: ", new_sock_fd);
    fprintf(plog_file, "Reading from %s\n", name);

    while(!pjob_data->end_of_program){
        n = read(new_sock_fd, buffer, BUFLEN-1);
        if ( n > 0 ) buffer[n] = '\0';  // add a \0 on success
        if(n<0){
            printf("Buffer: %s", buffer);
            error("Reading Failed");
        }
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex);
        if(n == 0){
            delete_socket(new_sock_fd, pjob_data);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < pjob_data->open_cnncts; i++){
            if(pjob_data->socket_ids[i] == new_sock_fd){
                continue;
            }
            m = write(pjob_data->socket_ids[i], name, strlen(name));
            if((m < 0)){
                error("Writing name failed");
            }
            n = write(pjob_data->socket_ids[i], buffer, strlen(buffer));
            if((n < 0)){
                error("Writing message failed");
            }
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex);
        printf("%s%s", name, buffer);
        fflush(stdout); //For unknown reason this is needed.
    }
    delete_socket(new_sock_fd, pjob_data);
    free(p);
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}

void* job_write(void* args){
    struct JOB_INFO* pjob_data = (struct JOB_INFO*)(args);
    fprintf(plog_file, "Started writing thread...\n");
    ssize_t n; //Error catching variable
    ssize_t m; //Error catching variable
    char buffer[BUFLEN];
    char* name = "Server: \0";

    while(!pjob_data->end_of_program) {
        fgets(buffer, BUFLEN, stdin);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex);
        for(int i = 0; i < pjob_data->open_cnncts; i++){
            m = write(pjob_data->socket_ids[i], name, strlen(name));
            if((m < 0)){
                error("Writing name failed");
            }
            n = write(pjob_data->socket_ids[i], buffer, strlen(buffer));
            if((n < 0)){
                error("Writing message failed");
            }
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex);
        if(strcmp("Bye\n", buffer) == 0){
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
    free(args);
    pjob_data->end_of_program = true;
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}

void enterConnectingLoop(struct SERVER_INFO* pserver_data, struct JOB_INFO* pjob_data, int sockfd){
    listen(sockfd, MAX_CONNECTIONS);

    for(pjob_data->open_cnncts = 0; (!pjob_data->end_of_program); /*mutex needs to be set*/ ){
        void** p = malloc(2*sizeof(void*));
        p[0] = (void*)pjob_data;
        p[1] = (void*)&(pjob_data->socket_ids[pjob_data->open_cnncts]);
        pjob_data->socket_ids[pjob_data->open_cnncts] =
                accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &pserver_data->cli_adr, &pserver_data->cli_len);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex)); //Note you cannot mutex the accept()
        printf("SOCKETFD %d\n", (pjob_data->socket_ids[pjob_data->open_cnncts]));
        fprintf(plog_file,"Client connected.\n");
        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread , NULL, job_read, p);
        pjob_data->open_cnncts++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex));
    }
}

void delete_socket(int socketid, struct JOB_INFO* pjob_data){
    bool found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < pjob_data->open_cnncts; i++){
        if(found){
            pjob_data->socket_ids[i-1] = pjob_data->socket_ids[i];
        }
        if(pjob_data->socket_ids[i] == socketid){
            close(socketid);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if(found){
        pjob_data->open_cnncts--;
    }
}

inline void setUpFileStream(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("Server started...\n");
    if(argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "You must provide a port number");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(argc == 3){
        plog_file = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    } else {
        plog_file = fopen("logfile.txt", "w");
    }
    plog_file = stdout;
    stderr = plog_file;
}

inline int setUpConnections(struct SERVER_INFO* pserver_data, char* port_numc){
    pserver_data->cli_len = sizeof(pserver_data->cli_adr);
    memset(&pserver_data->serv_add, 0, sizeof((pserver_data->serv_add)));

    uint16_t port_num = (uint16_t)atoi(port_numc);
    pserver_data->serv_add.sin_family = AF_INET;
    pserver_data->serv_add.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    pserver_data->serv_add.sin_port = htons(port_num);

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0){
        error("Error opening socket.");
    }

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) (&pserver_data->serv_add), sizeof(pserver_data->serv_add)) < 0){
        error("Binding failed.");
    }
    return sockfd;
}", buffer) == 0){
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
    free(args);
    pjob_data->end_of_program = true;
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}

void enterConnectingLoop(struct SERVER_INFO* pserver_data, struct JOB_INFO* pjob_data, int sockfd){
    listen(sockfd, MAX_CONNECTIONS);

    for(pjob_data->open_cnncts = 0; (!pjob_data->end_of_program); /*mutex needs to be set*/ ){
        void** p = malloc(2*sizeof(void*));
        p[0] = (void*)pjob_data;
        p[1] = (void*)&(pjob_data->socket_ids[pjob_data->open_cnncts]);
        pjob_data->socket_ids[pjob_data->open_cnncts] =
                accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &pserver_data->cli_adr, &pserver_data->cli_len);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex)); //Note you cannot mutex the accept()
        printf("SOCKETFD %d\n", (pjob_data->socket_ids[pjob_data->open_cnncts]));
        fprintf(plog_file,"Client connected.\n");
        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread , NULL, job_read, p);
        pjob_data->open_cnncts++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex));
    }
}

void delete_socket(int socketid, struct JOB_INFO* pjob_data){
    bool found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < pjob_data->open_cnncts; i++){
        if(found){
            pjob_data->socket_ids[i-1] = pjob_data->socket_ids[i];
        }
        if(pjob_data->socket_ids[i] == socketid){
            close(socketid);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if(found){
        pjob_data->open_cnncts--;
    }
}

inline void setUpFileStream(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("Server started...\n");
    if(argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "You must provide a port number");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(argc == 3){
        plog_file = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    } else {
        plog_file = fopen("logfile.txt", "w");
    }
    plog_file = stdout;
    stderr = plog_file;
}

inline int setUpConnections(struct SERVER_INFO* pserver_data, char* port_numc){
    pserver_data->cli_len = sizeof(pserver_data->cli_adr);
    memset(&pserver_data->serv_add, 0, sizeof((pserver_data->serv_add)));

    uint16_t port_num = (uint16_t)atoi(port_numc);
    pserver_data->serv_add.sin_family = AF_INET;
    pserver_data->serv_add.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    pserver_data->serv_add.sin_port = htons(port_num);

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0){
        error("Error opening socket.");
    }

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) (&pserver_data->serv_add), sizeof(pserver_data->serv_add)) < 0){
        error("Binding failed.");
    }
    return sockfd;
}
```

Within the job function, the Server seems to print the last message of the Client over and over again.

```
void* job_read(void * p){

    char** pc = (char**)p; //allow pointer arithmetic
    int new_sock_fd = *((int*) (pc[1]));  //Casting
    struct JOB_INFO* pjob_data = ((struct JOB_INFO*) (pc[0])); //Casting

    ssize_t n; //Error catching variable
    ssize_t m; //Error catching variable
    char buffer[BUFLEN];
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    sprintf(name, "Client %d: ", new_sock_fd);
    fprintf(plog_file, "Reading from %s\n", name);

    while(!pjob_data->end_of_program){
        n = read(new_sock_fd, buffer, BUFLEN-1);
        if ( n > 0 ) buffer[n] = '\0';  // add a \0 on success
        if(n<0){
            printf("Buffer: %s", buffer);
            error("Reading Failed");
        }
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex);
        if(n == 0){
            delete_socket(new_sock_fd, pjob_data);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < pjob_data->open_cnncts; i++){
            if(pjob_data->socket_ids[i] == new_sock_fd){
                continue;
            }
            m = write(pjob_data->socket_ids[i], name, strlen(name));
            if((m < 0)){
                error("Writing name failed");
            }
            n = write(pjob_data->socket_ids[i], buffer, strlen(buffer));
            if((n < 0)){
                error("Writing message failed");
            }
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex);
        printf("%s%s", name, buffer);
        fflush(stdout); //For unknown reason this is needed.
    }
    delete_socket(new_sock_fd, pjob_data);
    free(p);
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}
```

There are two things. Within this function, the name variable seems to disappear from time to time.  She does not get printed nor sent. But as far as I know, the name variable is always initialized.

**Reproduce the bug:**

Compile Server and Client(code below). 
Start Server and open a port:

```
./Server 9999
```

Start Client:

```
./Client 127.0.0.1 9999
```

Type something in the client.
Exit the client by closing the terminal.
Server behaves faulty.

Thank you!

Client Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUFLEN 255

bool endprogram = false;
int sockfd;

void error(const char* msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

void* job_read(void* p){
    char buffer[BUFLEN];
    while(!endprogram){
        bzero(buffer, BUFLEN);
        ssize_t n = read(sockfd, buffer, (BUFLEN));
        if(n < 0){
            error("Error on reading");
        }
        printf("%s", buffer);
        int i = strncmp("Bye", buffer, 3);
        if(i == 0){
            endprogram = true;
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
    }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    pthread_t readt;

    int16_t portnum;
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    struct hostent* server;

    if(argc < 3){
        perror("You shall provide a port and a ip adress");
    }
    portnum = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0){
        error("Error opening socket");
    }

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if(!server){
        error("No such host");
    }

    bzero((char*)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr_list[0], (char *)&serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr, sizeof(server->h_length));
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(portnum);

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr))<0){
        error("Connection failed");
    }

    pthread_create(&readt, NULL, &job_read, NULL);

    ssize_t n;
    char buffer[BUFLEN];
    while(!endprogram){
        fgets(buffer, BUFLEN, stdin);
        n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        if(n < 0){
            error("Error on writing");
        }
        n = strcmp(buffer, "Bye");
        if(n == 0){
            endprogram = true;
        }
    }
    pthread_join(readt, NULL);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

It is really hard to reduce the problem since I need all these methods to either set the problem up or to maintain core-functionality. However, this is the first reducement (uncompilable), where the bug might be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUFLEN 255
#define MAX_CONNECTIONS 128
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 30

struct JOB_INFO {
    int socket_ids[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
    bool end_of_program;
    int open_cnncts;
    pthread_mutex_t socketids_changingMutex;
};

struct SERVER_INFO {
    struct sockaddr_in serv_add;
    struct sockaddr_in cli_adr;
    socklen_t cli_len;
    pthread_t write_thread;
};
//Global Variables
FILE* plog_file;

void delete_socket(int socketid, struct JOB_INFO* pjob_data);
void* job_read(void*);
void error(const char* msg);
void enterConnectingLoop(struct SERVER_INFO* pserver_data, struct JOB_INFO* pjob_data, int sockfd);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int sock_fd;
    struct JOB_INFO job_data;
    job_data.end_of_program = false;
    job_data.open_cnncts = 0;

    struct SERVER_INFO server_data;
    enterConnectingLoop(&server_data, &job_data, sock_fd);

    job_data.end_of_program = true;
    close(sock_fd);

    pthread_join(server_data.write_thread, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&job_data.socketids_changingMutex);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void* job_read(void * p){

    char** pc = (char**)p; //allow pointer arithmetic
    int new_sock_fd = *((int*) (pc[1]));  //Casting
    struct JOB_INFO* pjob_data = ((struct JOB_INFO*) (pc[0])); //Casting

    ssize_t n; //Error catching variable
    ssize_t m; //Error catching variable
    char buffer[BUFLEN];
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    sprintf(name, "Client %d: ", new_sock_fd);
    fprintf(plog_file, "Reading from %s\n", name);

    while(!pjob_data->end_of_program){
        n = read(new_sock_fd, buffer, BUFLEN-1);
        if ( n > 0 ) buffer[n] = '\0';  // add a \0 on success
        if(n<0){
            printf("Buffer: %s", buffer);
            error("Reading Failed");
        }
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex);
        if(n == 0){
            delete_socket(new_sock_fd, pjob_data);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < pjob_data->open_cnncts; i++){
            if(pjob_data->socket_ids[i] == new_sock_fd){
                continue;
            }
            m = write(pjob_data->socket_ids[i], name, strlen(name));
            if((m < 0)){
                error("Writing name failed");
            }
            n = write(pjob_data->socket_ids[i], buffer, strlen(buffer));
            if((n < 0)){
                error("Writing message failed");
            }
        }
        printf("%s%s", name, buffer);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex);
        fflush(stdout); //For unknown reason this is needed.
    }
    delete_socket(new_sock_fd, pjob_data);
    free(p);
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}

void enterConnectingLoop(struct SERVER_INFO* pserver_data, struct JOB_INFO* pjob_data, int sockfd){
    listen(sockfd, MAX_CONNECTIONS);

    for(pjob_data->open_cnncts = 0; (!pjob_data->end_of_program); /*mutex needs to be set*/ ){
        void** p = malloc(2*sizeof(void*));
        p[0] = (void*)pjob_data;
        p[1] = (void*)&(pjob_data->socket_ids[pjob_data->open_cnncts]);
        pjob_data->socket_ids[pjob_data->open_cnncts] =
                accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &pserver_data->cli_adr, &pserver_data->cli_len);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex)); //Note you cannot mutex the accept()
        printf("SOCKETFD %d\n", (pjob_data->socket_ids[pjob_data->open_cnncts]));
        fprintf(plog_file,"Client connected.\n");
        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread , NULL, job_read, p);
        pjob_data->open_cnncts++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex));
    }
}

void delete_socket(int socketid, struct JOB_INFO* pjob_data){
    bool found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < pjob_data->open_cnncts; i++){
        if(found){
            pjob_data->socket_ids[i-1] = pjob_data->socket_ids[i];
        }
        if(pjob_data->socket_ids[i] == socketid){
            close(socketid);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if(found){
        pjob_data->open_cnncts--;
    }
}
```

I will try to set up a program which will do the same thing on a pc using input and output file and thereby surrounding this whole inet-setup-monster...

**EDIT EDIT:**

If the same thing happens outside if an IDE, I get an coredump - instead of stupid output: similar to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void* job_read(void* p){
    sleep(1000); //delay to ensure job_write is waiting
    FILE* pfile = ((FILE**)p)[0];
    while(1){
        char buffer[20];
        fgets(buffer, 19, pfile);
        printf("&s", buffer);
    }

}

void* job_write(void* p){
    FILE* pfile = ((FILE**)p)[0];
    fputs("hi\n", pfile);
    sleep(1200); //delay to ensure job_write is waiting
    pthread_exit(NULL); //FUCK THE OPEN CONNECTION
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    (void)argv; //Compiler things
    (void)argc;
    printf("HERE");
    FILE* in = fopen("in.txt", "w");
    pthread_t firstread; //Simulate all threads in actual IO: Server
    pthread_t firstwrite; //Client

    FILE** p = malloc(sizeof(FILE*));
    p[0] = in;

    pthread_create(&firstwrite, NULL, job_write, (void*)&p);
    pthread_create(&firstread, NULL, job_read, (void*)&p);

    pthread_join(firstwrite, NULL);
}
```

I guess this might be the solution to my actual problem. My assumption is that I try to write a file which no longer exists or something like this. however, I guess it is because of a closed file causing the bug

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**

I can safely say, that the problem is caused by the job_read function.
As commented, a smart user realzed that if the terminal quits it will take some time, before the actual process gets killed. This might cause one of the errors.

Comment: There is a wall of code there. An observation: "there might be a handful of other bugs" so the reason for misbehaviour can be *anything*?

Comment: Regarding `fflush(stdout); //For unknown reason this is needed.` That's to ensure the output is sent when you are debugging, since the preceding output does not send a newline. When a program terminates unexpectedly, buffered output is lost.

Comment: Oops that first big code block is copy/paste error anyway, stopping mid-flow and continuing with what was already there, so two `main` functions for example.

Comment: No, the bug cannot be anything. There might be other bugs with other symptoms, but there is only one bug causing this behavior

Thank you for your info about fflush.

Comment: What I mean, is that you think there are bugs in the code, their *result* can be anything. If you don't know what is wrong, how do you know there is "only one bug" when you already said there are more?

Comment: This isn't your own code?

Comment: It is my own code. (95% of it)

What I mean with "there might be other bugs". There might be other results which are not wished, but I have not discovered them yet.

I have fixed the twice copied code. Thank you!

Comment: There is way too much code here for us to be able to help. Trim it down to a [*minimal* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can actually understand the issue. Note that the process of trimming down your code often exposes the error by reducing complexity.

Comment: That is it. I tried that. But how do I trim it down when all the other junk is there. I will try again and edit my answer then!

Comment: If you close by closing the terminal is that an unexpected exit? If so, where does `pjob_data->end_of_program` get set, on which the loop `while(!pjob_data->end_of_program)` depends?

Comment: Yes; closing the terminal is an unexpected scenario. But it is not the end_of_program since there might be other clients. If the connection is closed, the process is supposed to exit the thread. (see 'if(n == 0){}'

Comment: @tadman
Edit
That is it. I tried that. But how do I trim it down when all the other junk is needed. I will try again and edit my answer then! – Niclas Schwalbe 9 mins ago

Comment: Most people here are prepared to spend, at most, five minutes helping you with a problem. If this really can't be trimmed down due to complexity and it will take longer to review, consider services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com) to engage with experts for in-depth problem solving.

Comment: Your client doesn't check for `fgets(buffer, BUFLEN, stdin)` returning an error. If the tty that's acting as stdin gets closed (because you closed the terminal window), fgets returns an error and leaves buffer untouched, so the client sends it again. A short time after that the client is killed by sighup. It doesn't always do this, though. stracing the client slows things down enough that the sighup gets received before the read completes.

Comment: True, but the problem is not clientsided...

Comment: I made a smart observation. Maybe you - guys - can now understand better what actually happens wrongly. See Edit Edit.

Comment: @NiclasSchwalbe *True, but the problem is not clientsided...*  How do you know that?  Try running something like Wireshark to see what actually goes through the connection (assuming it's a TCP connection between machines).

Comment: I think I will go for that, however, if the terminal gets closed, should not the process be abrupted?

Comment: @NiclasSchwalbe It will be, but as mentioned above in the comments, that may take some time to happen, and it might happen after the process gets a failed read from `stdin`.  And once the error or eof flag gets set on `stdin` (that's implementation-dependent), `fgets()` will return **fast** and not modify the contents of the buffer.  I can easily see that loop running a lot of times before the signal to end the process gets both queued and delivered.

Comment: Okay. This explains something. Do you have any idea why the Server stops writing Clients name? I can safely say that the only code causing the problem, is the job_read function...

Comment: @AndrewHenle But even if it is the client's fault, I have to rule on server-side, because otherwise, this would actually be a small hack...

Comment: Does flushing the stdout affect stdin?

Answer (score 1):

This code will repeat the last line read from `stdin` over and over if the input stream is closed:

```
while(!pjob_data->end_of_program) {
    fgets(buffer, BUFLEN, stdin);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex);
    for(int i = 0; i < pjob_data->open_cnncts; i++){
        m = write(pjob_data->socket_ids[i], name, strlen(name));
        if((m < 0)){
            error("Writing name failed");
        }
        n = write(pjob_data->socket_ids[i], buffer, strlen(buffer));
        if((n < 0)){
            error("Writing message failed");
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex);
    if(strcmp("Bye\n", buffer) == 0){
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

You never check if `fgets()` fails.  When it does, the previous contents of `buffer` are written to the socket.  And then the loop repeats over and over as long as `pjob_data->end_of_program` doesn't evaluate to true, sending the contents of `buffer` each time.  Likely really quickly, too.

EDIT:

The same error exists in the client code:

```
while(!endprogram){
    fgets(buffer, BUFLEN, stdin);
    n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if(n < 0){
        error("Error on writing");
    }
    n = strcmp(buffer, "Bye");
    if(n == 0){
        endprogram = true;
    }
}
```

The fix is to check the return value from `fgets()` and if `NULL`, act appropriately.  I haven't analyzed the code enough to know what "appropriately" means.

This code calls `pthread_exit()` with the mutex locked:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex);
    if(n == 0){
        delete_socket(new_sock_fd, pjob_data);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
```

Any attempt to lock or unlock the `pjob_data->socketids_changingMutex` after this will likely fail silently, or deadlock.

Comment: if(fgets(buffer, BUFLEN, stdin) == NULL){
         continue;
        }

Unfortunately, error still exists...

Comment: @NiclasSchwalbe Have you tried something like Wireshark to see if the packets actually get sent?  You might have to use the actual IP address of your system instead lf `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I have a actually a really hard time interpreting what i see... If i use my actual ip-adress would this require me to open port on router?

Comment: If you can't get Wireshark to work, just start your server with  `strace -f ./server 9999` to see what the server reads from the socket.